# Prestashop categories as dropdown in Header Menu

Tags: categories, prestashop

This question is regarding Prestashop.

I want to show the category listing in my custom header menu. I do not want to add any third party module to show the same. Please let me know which code snippet I should paste in the header menu section?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Should I use any third party API/code snippet for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the module I believe is called "Top Menu". You can add different categories and different CMS pages as you wish. Check it out! PrestaShop 1.5.2

Comment: Please look it up and provide bit more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop 1.5 add this feature as default.